# Search results show hidden tabs in excel

Tags: 2013, search-results, excel

I have a problem that concerns the search function, I have it set to search only in a specific library, which works perfectly. However, it works a bit too well. It actually searches among my hidden tabs in excel. There is nothing secret there, but it confuses the user

Is this something that can be changed?